# OpenGL window immediately closes with error -1073740777 (0xc0000417)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and OpenGL to create a simulation. 
Ideally, the window that I'm creating should stay open so that I can make changes using the keys and I can view a different result on the same window.
But the window closes immediately after it launches with error code

> program.exe' has exited with code -1073740777 (0xc0000417)

I did some debugging and tried commenting on various lines and saw that if I made 'glutSwapBuffers()' as a comment, the window stays open but empty.

Can someone please shed any light on this?

```
void keyboard (unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
 switch (key)
 {
    case 'r': case 'R':
    if (filling==0)
    {
        glPolygonMode (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL); 
        filling=1;
    }
    else
    {
        glPolygonMode (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_POINT); 
        filling=0;
    }
    break;
    case 27:
    exit(0);
    break;
 }
}
```

.

```
void display(void)
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
glLoadIdentity(); 
glRotatef(-90,0.0,1.0,0.0); 
glRotatef(-90,1.0,0.0,0.0); 

rotation_x = rotation_x + (rotation_x_increment - rotation_x)/50;
rotation_y = rotation_y + (rotation_y_increment - rotation_y)/50;
rotation_z = rotation_z + rotation_z_increment;

if (rotation_x > 359) rotation_x = 0;
if (rotation_y > 359) rotation_y = 0;
if (rotation_z > 359) rotation_z = 0;

if(rotation_x_increment > 359) rotation_x_increment = 0;
if(rotation_y_increment > 359) rotation_y_increment = 0;
if(rotation_z_increment > 359) rotation_z_increment = 0;

glRotatef(rotation_x,1.0,0.0,0.0); 
glRotatef(rotation_y,0.0,1.0,0.0);
glRotatef(rotation_z,0.0,0.0,1.0);

glTranslatef(x_translate,0.0,0.0);
glTranslatef(0.0,y_translate,0.0);
glTranslatef(0,0,z_translate); 

glFlush(); // This force the execution of OpenGL commands
glutSwapBuffers(); 
glFinish();
}
```

.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
IntroDisplay();
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(screen_width,screen_height);
glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
glutCreateWindow("Ultrasonic Testing");
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutIdleFunc(display);
glutReshapeFunc (resize);
glutKeyboardFunc (keyboard);
glutSpecialFunc (keyboard_s);
glutMouseFunc(mouse);
glutMotionFunc(mouseMove);
init();
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: STATUS_INVALID_CRUNTIME_PARAMETER - probably mixed crts or the likes, rebuild everything from source

Comment: @paulm Tried rebuilding. Tried cleaning and rebuilding. Still no change.
Could it be something related to windows or glut32.dll? Because I haven't changed the code for a while and it suddenly started doing this.

Comment: You still have a `glEnd` without a corresponding `glBegin`.

Comment: @BDL I removed the glEnd. Still no change.

Comment: have you updated your graphics driver?

Comment: @Amadeus I recently updated it to the latest driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was something to do with my drivers. It worked fine after I  reinstalled everything.

I think it's because swap function also depends on the system and not the just the library. I read that somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try compiling and running an absolutely minimal, bare bones program that does nothing except creating a window with GLUT, registering a display function that just clears and swaps the buffers and that's it. I.e. this

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
static void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutCreateWindow("test");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(glutPostRedisplay);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

My guess at the cause of your troubles is, that some library you're using was built with a different compiler than the one you're using and differences in the expected runtimes cause some hickups for you. If the minimal program given above crashes, then this is the most likely cause.

Note that in your code the calls to `glFinish` and `glFlush` are superfluous, because flushing and finishing is implied by a buffer swap. Also it's usually not a good idea to register the display function as GLUT idle handler; register glutPostRedisplay instead if you need a continuous display update.

Comment: I tried the minimal program and it crashes too. What do you suggest I do to fix the runtime errors?

Comment: @RahulK: Since you mentioned that the problem appears when glutSwapBuffers is called your particular build of GLUT seems to be the culprit. Your best course of action is to pull the sources for FreeGLUT ( http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/freeglut/freeglut-3.0.0.tar.gz?download ) and build it yourself with your own compiler. Actually it makes a lot of sense to simply drop FreeGLUT into your project and add it to your VisualStudio project as a solution, so that it gets built together with your main program.

Comment: I got it fixed. I reinstalled the entire Visual Studio and all the updates. Still not sure what the exact problem was though. Thanks a lot for the help. :)